# How does Laravel phpunit test assertion "$this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user, $guard = null)" work?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, sanctum

I am trying to test if a user is authenticated by using the "assertAuthenticatedAs" method.
The method is fairly simple. It accepts the model instance and guard.
But the following code will fail the test.

```
public function test_regsiter_a_user(): void
{
    $existingUsersCount = User::query()->count();
    $response = $this->postJson('/api/auth/register', [
        'email' => fake()->safeEmail(),
        'name' => fake()->firstName(),
        'password' => 'password',
        'password_confirmation' => 'password',
    ]);
    $this->assertDatabaseCount('users', $existingUsersCount + 1);
    $this->assertDatabaseCount('personal_access_tokens', 1);
    $response->assertCreated();
    $user = User::query()->where('email', $response->json()['user']['email'])->first();

    // $token = $response->json()['token'];
    // $this->getJson('api/user', headers: [
    //     'Authorization' => "Bearer $token"
    // ])->assertOk();

    $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user, 'sanctum');
}
```

The strange thing is if I uncomment the code,

```
$token = $response->json()['token'];
$this->getJson('api/user', headers: [
        'Authorization' => "Bearer $token"
    ])->assertOk();
```

The assertion `$this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user, 'sanctum');` will pass.

My controller's register method is the following.

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users,email'],
            'name' => ['required'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed'],
        ]);

        $user = User::query()->create($data)->fresh();

        $token = $user->createToken('email');

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token->plainTextToken,
        ], HttpStatus::CREATED->value);
    }
```

Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: when u do `/login`, then u are authenticated, otherwise u are not. the `assertAuthenticatedAs` is cookie assertion.